# Deadlock in Uploading file of gz compression with multiple parts from hfds to s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have a job that outputs many files to hfds. The files are .gz compression
But there are files with 2-3 blocks

I'm using the following code to upload the files from hdfs to s3

```
   FileSystem fileSystem = fileSystem = FileSystem.get(config);
   Path srcHdfsDirPath = new Path(sourcePath);
   Path[] paths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(fileSystem.listStatus(srcHdfsDirPath, new OutputFilesFilter()));
     for (Path srcPath : paths) {
            InputStream in = fileSystem.open(srcPath);
            try {
                uploadFileToAmazon(srcPath.getName(), in, fileSystem.getFileStatus(srcPath).getLen(), destinationPath + "/" + srcPath.getName(), s3Client);
            }finally {
                in.close();
            }
        }


   ---------
 protected void uploadFileToAmazon(InputStream source, long length, String amazonPath, AmazonS3Client s3Client) throws UploadFailed {

 List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(
            bucketName, amazonPath);
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse =
            s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

    // Step 2: Upload parts.
    long filePosition = 0;
    for (int i = 1; filePosition < length; i++) {
        // Last part can be less than 5 MB. Adjust part size.
        long currentPartSize = Math.min(partSize, (length - filePosition));


        // Create request to upload a part.
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName).withKey(amazonPath)
                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(i)
                .withFileOffset(filePosition)
                .withInputStream(source)
                .withPartSize(currentPartSize);

        logger.info("upload part {}", i);
        boolean anotherPass;
        int attempts = 0;
        do {
            anotherPass = false;  // assume everythings ok
            try {
                // Upload part and add response to our list.
                partETags.add(s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                anotherPass = true; // repeat
                attempts++;
            }
        }while (anotherPass && attempts < maxLoadAttempts);

        if (attempts == maxLoadAttempts){
            throw new UploadFailed("failed to upload data to amazon");
        }

        filePosition += partSize;
    }

    logger.info("complete upload request");
    // Step 3: Complete.
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new
            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucketName,
            amazonPath,
            initResponse.getUploadId(),
            partETags);

    s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
```

All this stucks on the first file when it uploads  the second part.

The thread dump shows the following:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.InputSubstream.read(InputSubstream.java:71)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.read(MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.java:98)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000007cb4bc718> (a com.amazonaws.internal.SdkBufferedInputStream)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkBufferedInputStream.read(SdkBufferedInputStream.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:151)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
    at org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:98)
    at com.amazonaws.http.RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.writeTo(RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:257)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:47)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:635)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:429)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:291)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3655)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doUploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:2770)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:2755)
    at com.mycomp.agg.common.aws.AmazonS3Util.uploadFileToAmazon(AmazonS3Util.java:197)
```

I suspect that the root cause is the gz (not splittable compression).
Is it possible to make this code work with also gz compression and the low level API?

Comment: How confusing; where do these `FileSystem` and `Path` class come from? They are not java.nio.file's

Comment: @fge, these are Hadoop's classes, in org.apache.hadoop.fs... indeed very confusing.